# Change a value in a file Java

Tags: java, file, text

So, I want to change a value in the file `Utilizadores.txt`
the default value is `zero` but when i click in the button the value has to change to 10 and every time i do a new one the value gets +10
the problem is when e try to do that the space where it should appear the (10/20/30...) appears blank

PS: it only changes in the lines of the file that have a certain ID(the id of my user)

```
private void ConfirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
    String filePath = "Reservas.txt";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    try { 
        FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);
        bw1.write(this.id+ "-" + cbxrestaurante.getSelectedItem().toString() + "-" + Dia.getText() + "-" + Hora.getText() + "-" + Lugares.getText());
        bw1.newLine();
        bw1.close();
        fw1.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClienteForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClienteForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    String filePath1 = "Utilizadores.txt";

    File file1 = new File(filePath1);

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file1);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1, true);
        PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter(fw);


        /*BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1, true);
        PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter((file1), "UTF-8");*/

       //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1, true)));


        Object[] lines = br.lines().toArray();
        Integer[] getPontos = new Integer[lines.length];
        String[] identificador = new String[lines.length];
        String[] cartao = new String[lines.length];
        String[] Pass = new String[lines.length];
        String[] Nome = new String[lines.length];
        String[] NIF = new String[lines.length];
        String[] Tele = new String[lines.length];
        String Zero = "zero";
        String[] Morada = new String[lines.length];
        String[] Localidade = new String[lines.length];
        String[] dono = new String[lines.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            String[] row = lines[i].toString().split("-");
            if (Objects.equals(Zero, row[10])||Integer.parseInt(row[10])==0) {
                  getPontos[i] = 0;

            } else {

                getPontos[i] = Integer.parseInt(row[10]);          
            }

            identificador[i] = row[1];
            cartao[i] = row[2];
            Pass[i] = row[3];
            Nome[i] = row[4];
            NIF[i] = row[5];
            Tele[i] = row[6];
            Morada[i] = row[7];
            Localidade[i] = row[8];
            dono[i] = row[9];
            if (Integer.parseInt(identificador[i]) == this.id) {
                if (getPontos[i] == 0) {
                    getPontos[i] = 10;
                } else {
                    getPontos[i] = getPontos[i] + 10;

                }
            }
        }
        fr.close();
        br.close();
        File temp = new File("Utilizadores.txt");
        if (temp.exists()) {
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(temp, "rw");
            raf.setLength(0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            bw.write("UserId-");

            bw.write(identificador[i] + "-");
            bw.write(cartao[i] + "-");
            bw.write(Pass[i] + "-");
            bw.write(Nome[i] + "-");
            bw.write(NIF[i] + "-");
            bw.write(Tele[i] + "-");
            bw.write(Morada[i] + "-");
            bw.write(Localidade[i] + "-");
            bw.write(dono[i] + "-");
            bw.write(getPontos[i]);
            bw.write("\r\n");

        }
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
        this.dispose();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Import nao funciona");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClienteForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to increment the 0 value and overwrite it? Then get the text from the file, convert to int then back to string and write to the file.

Comment: when i do System.out.println(getPontos[i]), in the output is right
output: 10
             0

but in the file is only a blank space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert your Integer to String: 
`bw.write( String.valueOf(getPontos[i]));`
instead
`bw.write(getPontos[i]);`

Comment: thank you, it works